# Call a regular function through lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

```
def guru(funct, *args):
    funct(*args)


def printer_one(arg):
    return print(arg)


def printer_two(arg):
    print(arg)

guru(lambda: printer_one('printer 1 LAMBDA CALL'))
guru(lambda: printer_two('printer 2 LAMBDA CALL'))
```

Can anyone please explain me why there is no comma and a colon after lambda for the function call.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: ```guru(lambda a=printer_two: [a,printer_one('printer 1 LAMBDA CALL')])```?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def main():
    def guru(funct, *args):
        funct()

    def printer_one(arg):
        return print(arg)

    def printer_two(arg):
        print(arg)

    # CALL A REGULAR FUNCTION THRU A LAMBDA
    guru(lambda: printer_one('printer 1 LAMBDA CALL'))
    guru(lambda: printer_two('printer 2 LAMBDA CALL'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when u use lambda u define a function and send it as arguments
so the *args in guru is empty
funct = lambda function so u have to run the funct in the guru

Comment: I want to know why guru forgives us for not providing the second argument.

Comment: in python when u use *args it gives you the tuple of argument you entered when you call the function if you dont pass any argument it just return empty tuple and it is totally fine. if u go like def func(a, b) and not providing any params you have problem